# Cocoa enumeration

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nserror

I'm creating a list of error codes as so

```
enum{
    firstErrorCode = 1,
    secondErrorCode = 2,
};
```

I would like to create an error domain-type concept for a custom error class (subclass of NSObject) I'm writing.

Is there any way I could associate this enumeration with a string name? For instance MyErrorDomain?

Comment: Possible dupe of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094984/convert-objective-c-typedef-to-its-string-equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to tie an enumeration to an error domain name. If you look in the Cocoa errors headers (FoundationErrors.h and CoreDataErrors.h), you'll see that no connection with `NSCocoaErrorDomain` is declared to the compiler; the connection is all in people's heads, expressed only in documentation.

So it is with your own error domain: You document, in comments and/or separate documentation, that these error codes go with that domain, and that is the maximal extent to which you can connect them.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a STATIC function in that class that handles this with a simple switch-case. You could ask what type you are dealing with and return the associated NSString.