# uitableviewcellAccessoryType from Json data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am getting json data where i also get value for what kind of accessory type i have to show for each row. It comes as follows:

```
{
accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
```

When I directly assign this value to `cell.accessoryType`, it does not show up.

I have tried prining it as a String, and it prints correctly.
How should I proceed? Can I convert NSSTring to UITableViewCellAccessoryType?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert objective-c typedef to its string equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094984/convert-objective-c-typedef-to-its-string-equivalent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` is an `NSInteger` from an enum.

`cell.accessoryType` expect an NSInteger as well. Since you don't know what integer represents the button types, you can't really convert directly between NSString and NSInteger.

Your options are:

1. Instead of seding `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` string in the JSON, you could send the integer value which represents in (not recommended, it might change since some button types get deprecated).
2. Verify the string like

.

```
NSString *accessoryString = [json objectForKey:accessoryType];

if (accessoryString isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton"]   {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
} else {
    //Other actions
}
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking. I had kept this option as the last. Isn't there any better way?

Comment: Never mind, your case is the same as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094984/convert-objective-c-typedef-to-its-string-equivalent And the answer for that is no.